# How can I make horizontal plane instances attached to branches using geometry nodes?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

My question is, how can I make planes that do not tilt on the tip of a geometry’s branches (which are also made by multiple instances in the geometry nodes) and stay horizontal.
To be more specific - I am trying to make one plane to be laid horizontally on each branch. However, It is a little complicated because the planes and branches are both instances.

I tried to calculate inverse rotation to an Instance on Plane node’s rotate curve tangent obtained by "Capture Attribute" or "Instance Rotate '' node, but the result is not as I expected.
Please let me know if someone has any suggestions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see you have capture attribute in point mode, but there are instances here, set capture attribute to instance mode

Comment: @Crantisz
I changed point to instance in capture attribute node. but I cloud not solve it.

Comment: Hi frisk, i am not sure what you want it look like? like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhUtD.png maybe add a sketch so we know what you want? thx

Comment: @Chris Thank you for try my blend file. But little bit different it i want to. I drew a sketch that is i want[ https://imgur.com/a/R5pHJ5j ]. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use realize instances to convert instances to real geometry:

[image]

To  Robin Betts:

Because cubes instanced not in the object space, but in each instance space. This is an instance inside an instance, and the inner instance inherits the rotation of the parent instance. Take a look at this example, how the line rotates with cubes instanced inside the line, and instance count remains equal to two:

[image]

In my example I rotated after instancing, but it may be before also, like OP did.

Comment: Same conclusion, but I can't work out why the cube instance should automatically pick up the rotation of the curve-line, when it hasn't been told anything about it. ... :(

Comment: @RobinBetts added explanation.

Comment: Hi @Crantisz, Thank you for solved my problem!! Your answer is perfect working!!

Comment: @Crantisz Thanks! I've got to revise my mental image of instances.. e.g. in the OP, curve instances seem to have 'Endpoints' before being realised ?!? It'll come, with time, I guess...

Comment: Endpoints are inside instance in curve.